# metadata of All THE FIELDS OF ALL THE OBJECTS

Tags: apex, soql, query, metadata, fields

We are trying to make a list of all the fields which we have created between our two consecutive releases.
We need the metadata of All THE FIELDS OF ALL THE OBJECTS for this reason, so that we can identify the fields created recently using the created date. We have about 407 objects. 
Please suggest any way that it can be done or if there are any applications which would assist in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Schema Lister.

Check the below link

https://schemalister.herokuapp.com/

1. Select your environment and API version
2. Authorize the Apps through OAuth and it will generate a list of all
   the objects and fields.

The benefit of using this app is that you don’t need to install anything in your Salesforce org and don’t need to provide your Salesforce username and password.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried it, however, it gives a list of objects, its fields, labels and api names and field type. It does not have other attributes like created date or modified date. We need these attributes to filter the fields based on when they were created. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The Metadata API will NOT return all the Object Names and Field Names. Instead, it provides a specific "view" of Custom Objects and Fields that are relevant to Metadata connections. Salesforce calls these "channels." You need to use the [SOAP Describe API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_list_describe.htm) to globally list all of the objects, and then Describe all of the fields. This will provide what you are asking for.